# Approximation of $ \Big| \frac{1}{1+z^{2}} \Big| $

Tags: complex-analysis

In Gamelin's Complex Analysis, it says $ \Big| \frac{1}{1+z^{2}} \Big| \le \Big| \frac{1}{R^{2} - 1} \Big| $ on a semicircle with radius R. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Do you mean $\le \dfrac{1}{|R^2-1|}?$

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\left|1+z^2\right| \geq \left|1-\left|z^2\right|\right|=|1-R^2|=|R^2-1|$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $z=Re^{i\theta}$ (because $z$ is on a semicircle) with $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ so $\Big|\frac{1}{1+z^2}\Big|=\Big|\frac{1}{1+R^2e^{2i\theta}}\Big|\le\Big|\frac{1}{1-R^2}\Big|=\frac{1}{|R^2-1|}$ for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.